# Creating forms for online use

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have been asked to create a form, where one can fill in their answer, (this will be a PDF, I am creating the form in InDesign). For some answers, three paragraphs will be required. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean with three paragraphs? Three different form fields? or just a field with a long text? When you create the form in Indesign will be just the structure, the form itself will be done at Acrobat I guess, and there you can decide how the answer field will be. Do you have a visual example to get an idea about what do you need?

Comment: "Online use"... Please be aware that all interactive PDF features (such as forms) are likely to be not working properly outside Acrobat Reader (or a Acrobat Pro)...You should be aware of it! A PHP webpage would probably much safer (I know, it's not as easy as making a PDF...)

Answer (score 2):

How to create multi-line text boxes.

1) Draw your text box.

2) Select your text box and go to Object -> Interactive -> Convert Into Text Field

3) Open Buttons and Forms Window by going to Window -> Interactive -> Buttons and Forms

4) Make sure font size is specified and not auto. Make sure Multiline is checked.